# Text not wrapping to an element floated right in IE 6 and 7

Tags: internet-explorer, word-wrap

I have the below HTML and CSS and I am trying to get the .metadata to float right and the text to wrap around it. It works fine on Firefox and current versions of IE but in IE6 and 7 the text doesn't wrap.  The Metadata box is floated to the right but whatever the height of the metadata box is, it's also pushing the text down by that much and the text will span across the width of #container.

In current browsers, the text wraps around the .metadata box.

```
#container { width: 960px; margin:0 auto;}
.metadata { float: right; width: 500px; }

<div id="container">
    <div class="metadata">
        <div class="metadataRow">
           <div class="metadataLeft">Name: </div>
           <div class="metadataRight">Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
```